# Defining a function for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm trying to define a function that selects a part of a dataframe, groups it by a column in the dataframe and attach a suffix to the column names

```
def diagnosis(x):
    x = df.query('x == 1').groupby('gender').count()
    return x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')
```

where:

diagnosis - funct name

x - column with criteria for selection

df - dataframe

This is the error when I run the code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [205], in <cell line: 5>()
      2     x = med_app_cleaned.query(x == 1).groupby('gender').count()
      3     return x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')
----> 5 diagnosis(hypertension)

Input In [205], in diagnosis(x)
      1 def diagnosis(x):
----> 2     x = med_app_cleaned.query(x == 1).groupby('gender').count()
      3     return x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4108, in DataFrame.query(self, expr, inplace, **kwargs)
   4106 if not isinstance(expr, str):
   4107     msg = f"expr must be a string to be evaluated, {type(expr)} given"
-> 4108     raise ValueError(msg)
   4109 kwargs["level"] = kwargs.pop("level", 0) + 1
   4110 kwargs["target"] = None

ValueError: expr must be a string to be evaluated, <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> given
```

Comment: Can you provide a short snippet to reproduce your data and then show what your expected output is? This is just the best way to avoid assumptions

Comment: What is `hypertension`?

Comment: @Vitalizzare column in the data frame

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two functions:

```
def diagnosis_v1(x):
    x = med_app_cleaned.query(x == 1).groupby('gender').count()
    return x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')

def diagnosis_v2(x):
    x = df.query('x == 1').groupby('gender').count()
    return x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')
```

As for the first one, we should pass to `query` a string as an argument, not a series. However, we can make it work with `where` instead of `query` in the first line:

```
x = med_app_cleaned.where(x == 1).groupby('gender').count()
```

The second function should work if we replace `x` in the query with its name:

```
x = df.query(f'{x.name} == 1').groupby('gender').count()
```

---

P.S. Notes below do not concern your question, but I think you might be interested.

**Note 1**
I couldn't read your intent regarding this line:

```
x.rename(lambda y: y[:11] + '_' + x[0], axis='columns')
```

It's definitely about renaming column names, but `x[0]` looks weird. Is there a `0` column in `df`? Should there be `x.name` of the initial `x` parameter in this place? I guess you might run into a `KeyError` here.

**Note 2**
It might be convenient to rename the level instead of renaming columns, sort of:

```
... .rename_axis(columns=x.name + "_eq_1")
```

where `x.name` is the name of a Series passed to the function.

**Note 3**
Not sure if it's a good practice to reuse a parameter name as a local variable. You lose connection to the parameter this way and can't use it later.

**Note 4**
If your original intent is to count the `gender` values in the filtered data, then I'd suggest to use `.value_counts`:

```
df.query(f'{x.name} == 1')['gender'].value_counts()
```

**Note 5**
Merely a proposal:

```
def diagnosis(column_name: str, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.Series:
    return (
        df
        .query(f'{column_name} == 1')
        .value_counts('gender')
        .rename(column_name + "_eq_1")
    )
```